# Socket call multiple time that first give me ui with update two time then merge with original response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sockets

//this is an function that receive real time msg that other user send.

api call to get conversation list...

```
  const handleListMyContact = useCallback(async () => {
    const data = await getConversation(authToken);
    if (data) {
      setListData(data.info);
    } else {
      console.log("loading data...");
    }
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (focus) {
      handleListMyContact();
    }
  }, [handleListMyContact, focus]);
```

```
const receivePersonalMessage = useCallback((data: any) => {
    console.log("data from emit", data);
    const contactList: any = listData;
    const idxObj = contactList.findIndex((object: any) => {
      return object.conversation_id === data.conversation_id;
    });
    console.log("object find....", idxObj);
    contactList.splice(idxObj, 1);
    contactList.unshift(data);
    console.log("contact list", contactList[0].message);
    setListData((prev: any) => [contactList[0], ...prev]);
    console.log("clicked...");
    handleListMyContact(); // this is my api call that code is above
  }, []);
```

//then I set socket globally. so in useEffect i direct call that socket.on instance.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("new_conversation_message", receivePersonalMessage);

    return () => {
      socket.off("new_conversation_message", receivePersonalMessage);
    };
  }, [socket, receivePersonalMessage]);
```

whenever other user send the msg at the conversation tab i can see first two response then it render with original one.

// this is log i got from receivePersonalMessage function

```
object find.... -1
contact list Hi
clicked...
object find.... -1
contact list Hi
clicked...
```

and the problem is first it shows me hi msg first time in alone then marge with group but actually I want hi msg should be direct update to the group not two times in another user screen then show in orginal group. could you please help me out? I really appreciate if you could help me. Thank you in advance